# How Do I Remove Extraneous Desktop Icons From Unauthorized Users On Windows Server 2016

Tags: windows-server-2016, desktop, icons

I have an application server into which multiple users log in daily, but some software that's been installed only for certain users crept into everyone's desktops with unwanted launch icons. How do I remove those?

PS: That software I speak of is already secured with credentials, but I just don't want the icons to be even visible to most users. Only one or two people need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there are only one or two people that really need the software launch icons, I'd suggest removing them from public access and only placing them on the desktop of users that really need them. There are two spots you can remove software launch icons that are visible to everyone on your application server.

**1. The Windows desktop**

Just visit C:\Users\Public\Desktop (literally type that into the Windows Explorer address bar to get there immediately; that folder is otherwise hidden from Windows Explorer). There, you can cut the unwanted application software icons from everyone's desktop with cut and paste functions (which is preferable, as opposed to deletion, if you want to later paste the icons elsewhere for another person to access). You can leave those icons behind that make sense for everyone to have (or add new ones you think they should all have!) If you cut the icons, you can them paste them on the desktops of the individuals who really need them, and their individual desktops are found in the path, C:\Users\*Username*\Desktop, where *Username* obviously stands in for the users' Windows login name.

**2. The Start menu**

Furthermore, you can remove programs from everyone's Start menu by cutting them from the subfolders found in C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs (again, I recommend cut/paste functions here instead of deleting the icons so you can then paste the icons elsewhere to a more private destination of your choice). Note that removing the icons from this public Start menu folder hierarchy will remove the visibility to those programs on the Start menu of your users but won't actually uninstall the software. However, usually taking the icons away like this is sufficient to discourage unauthorized users from finding and launching the software on the server that you won't wish them to have access to. Finally, you can take the icons you cut off the public Start menu and paste them into your intended individual users' private Start menus, accessible at C:\Users\*Username*\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs.

Obviously, if that shared software on your application server would give some users access to sensitive data they shouldn't at all be able to view, you need to implement stricter authorization/authentication methods than just the above--but that's another topic.